# What is the good batch size for large datasets?

Tags: python-3.x, keras, jupyter-notebook

I am working on a dataset of 45000 images.

1)How much batch size should i use for large datasets like this.?

2)And what optimiser should I  use like Adam or SGD ,I have bit confusion always to choose optimiser.

Environment:
I7-8750h and GTX 1060(6GB).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on your computational resources and your problem.

- from the point view of efficient processing, you should try different batch sizes and see which makes the batch preparation time (by CPU) and the training time (by GPU) compatible. Ideally, we want the batch GPU time is slightly longer than the batch CPU time.
- from the point view of best utilizing GPU, you want to fit a batch while not eating up all your GPU memory.

The Rule of thumb for a good batch size is 16 or 32 for most computer vision problems. However, in many problems, e.g. image semantic segmentation, you might not be able to fit such a batch to your GPU memory. Consequently, people also reduce the batch size accordingly.

Finally, it is worthy mention that:

- a too large batch size (e.g. 1024) could hamper the training process unless you do additional things to handle potential issues
- batch size and learning rate are not two independent variables, if you modify a batch size, you'd better adjust the learning rate accordingly.

Comment: Plus small batch size with small diversity of objects in the batch could hamper learning.